# How does the parameter scaleFactor in detectMultiScale affect face detection?

Tags: opencv

I am trying out a slight variation of the example from http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

```
    CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
    Mat image = Highgui.imread(originalFile.getAbsolutePath());
    MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
    double w = ((double)originalCrop.getWidth());
    double h = ((double)originalCrop.getHeight());
    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections, 3, 1, 
                   Objdetect.CASCADE_DO_CANNY_PRUNING , new Size(w/16, h/16), new Size(w/2, h/2));
```

From the API: scaleFactor – Parameter specifying how much the image size is reduced at each image scale.

Changing the scaleFactor changes what is detected. For example, for the following image:
http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2013/04/02/world/MOSCOW/MOSCOW-articleLarge-v2.jpg

scaleFactor of 3 --> Gorbachev's face is not detected
scaleFactor of 2 --> Gorbachev's face is detected twice (one larger rectangle containing a smaller one)
scaleFactor of 1.01 ---> Gorbachev's face is detected once

How exactly does this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered over at the [opencv forum](http://answers.opencv.org/question/10654/how-does-the-parameter-scalefactor-in/?answer=10703#post-id-10703):

> Basically the scale factor is used to create your scale pyramid. More
>   explanation can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/5kk73gpu2012/assignment/viola-jones-face-detection#TOC-Image-Pyramid). In short. Your model has a fixed
>   size defined during training. This means that this size of face is
>   detected in the image if occuring. However, by rescaling the input
>   image, you can resize a larger face towards a smaller one, making it
>   detectable for the algorithm. Using a small step for resizing, for
>   example 1.05 which means you reduce size by 5 %, you increase the
>   chance of a matching size with the model for detection is found.